# Gnome Shell Extension Programming DND library issue

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, gnome-3, gnome-shell-extensions

I've been tinkering around with the code of the Arc Menu Gnome Shell extension. My goal is to give it the ability to drag programs to the desktop (if the user has it enabled, of course).

The "vanilla" GNOME menu extension provides this feature and from the code it seemed simple enough to implement. Arc is partially based on this menu so it share many similarities with it.

I have imported the libraries it needs and anything else I can think of to "mimic the way the "vanilla" menu does it.

However, when I drag icons they will drag, but not release. This is progress but definitely not success.

Links to the code. https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ar9u8yuRj5D8ko0Acb_GRHxWzrnGxQ

`menu.js` and `menuwidgets.js` are from Arc.

`extension.js` is from the "vanilla" extension.

I hope I've provided enough context and someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Well, I don't know much about DND, but two thing that will help greatly are to have `journalctl -f -o cat /usr/bin/gnome-shell` running in a terminal and use copious amounts of `log()` calls to see whats happening. Without an expectation of what the *code* should be doing and output of what it is doing, you won't make much progress. Try and update with some details in that vein.

Comment: here is the error that is outputted when i drag to the desktop: JS ERROR: Exception in callback for signal: drag-end: TypeError: Main.legacyTray is undefined
ApplicationMenuItem<._init/<@/home/josh/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/arc-menu@linxgem33.com/menuWidgets.js:372:13
_emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:126:27
_Draggable<._onAnimationComplete@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/dnd.js:640:9
wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
_addHandler/params[name]@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:91:13

Comment: You must be using Gnome 3.26 then as that element was removed after 3.24. From glancing at the code, it only seems to be hidden and shown on drag events so it's probably safe to just remove those callbacks.